# .Net tool to Document Methods

Tags: c#, .net

I have been asked by my company to document all of our .Net web services and provide the signatures (ie inputs and outputs) for all the methods of those services. Is there a tool out there that will do this and return a document or summary. This would save me a lot of time and stop me from having to look through a bunch of code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) for this with pretty good success. You can see examples linked from [this page](http://www.doxygen.nl/projects.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, now I just have to document in code :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add XML comments to methods like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method summary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "asdf">Parameter description.</param>
    /// <returns>Return value summary.</returns>
    public object SomeMethod(object asdf) {
        return null; // but really, do something fun
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) is great for getting an initial start to documenting undocumented code.

The XML docs can then be exported via [SandCastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/), a good UI frontend for Sandcastle, resulting in HTMLHelp, HTML, and MS Help File Viewer outputs.

Answer (score 1):

[Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/).
See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/latishsehgal/archive/2009/04/17/creating-msdn-like-help-using-sandcastle.aspx) on a quick how-to.
[Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=SHFB) is extremely useful.

Sandcastle creates msdn like documentation. We use GhostDoc within Visual Studio to do the actual commenting on everything.

Answer (score 1):

Sancastle is the most used one I think.

Amongst others there's:

- [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/)
- [Docu](http://docu.jagregory.com/)
- [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

If you do not have existing XML comments in the source code, [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) plugin offers great help in generating standard boilerplate comments which can be modified later.